# Delete Word Document from location - VB UFT

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, hp-uft

As suggested in the title, it looks like a simple question but i didn't find any solution so far.
So i would like to delete a Word document from a file system, share, file explorer; so any location.
I didn't find a way to deal with that concern.
I've tried simple DeleteFile function but it seems it doesn't handle word file.

```vb
Function DeleteAFile(filespec)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.DeleteFile(filespec)
End Function
```

The same i tried creating a oWord object ( an instance of a COM component ) but there is no delete method or event available.

```vb
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.'No method nor event for delete action
```

So i'm blocked.
Is someone having a solution, it would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try `File.Delete()` or `System.IO.Directory.Delete()`?  I don't know anything about UFT but maybe you can access these methods?

Comment: Thx. Are those methods in vb ?

Comment: They're VB.Net, and you'd normally need the System.IO namespace.  Google them both to get the MS Docs on all the overrides so you know the right way to call them, assuming that you can do so from UFT.

Comment: I had a look over the documentation. I don't think it suits to UFT. Those methods are specific to .NET environment. And not working with UFT

Comment: Please confirm -- are you working in VBScript or VB.NET? Those are two very different environments. Adjust the tags accordingly. Also, what are you trying to do -- delete a file from the file system, or shutdown a running Word process?

Comment: Assuming you're working in VBScript, what happens when you try to run `fso.DeleteFile`? Is it simply failing silently, or are you getting some kind of error; and if you are getting an error, what is it?

Comment: Iam working with VBScript. I did the edit. I didn't see this error sorry.

Comment: And nothing is happening if i run fso.DeleteFile. The file remains and no error message.

Comment: The file remains and no error message and delete is working with xml but not with word or RTF in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA or VB.Net the simple command is:

```
Kill(Path and Filename)
```

Based on additional information provided in the comments that only VBScript can now be used. You should consider two factors. The files you are trying to delete are Read Only and you have to then use the Force option on the DeleteFile method. The other is that your routine is receiving some error condition and thus the DeleteFile method is being stopped. You should add error checking to your routine.

For further information on the FileDelete method see the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/deletefile-method

Comment: Thx. I will have  a look. I let you know.

Comment: I only know that it works in VBA and VB.Net ... you originally tagged your question with VB.Net, and that is why I offered the solution. Now I see you have removed that tag. I haven't used VBScript, so I can't say if the Kill function works with it. From a quick search it looks like the FSO function is your only choice.

Comment: Thanks. I will dig out this solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional information about the FileDelete method.